# Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a bijective map, and let $P,Q \subseteq A$ be any sets. Then $f(P-Q)=f(P)-f(Q)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Can you please check my proof of the following theorem?

> **Theorem:** Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a bijective map, and let $P,Q \subseteq A$ be any sets. Then $f(P-Q)=f(P)-f(Q)$.

> **Proof:** Let $x \in f(P)-f(Q)$. Hence $x \in f(P)$ and $x \notin f(Q)$. From the former, we deduce that there exists some $a \in P$ such that $f(a)=x$. Let $a_0 \in P$ that element. We know that $f(a_0) \notin f(Q)$, so $a_0 \notin Q$. Then we have that $a_0 \in P-Q$ and it follows that $x=f(a_0) \in f(P-Q)$. Therefore $f(P)-f(Q) \subseteq f(P-Q)$.
>
> Let $y \in f(P-Q)$. Since $f$ is bijective, there is only one $b \in P-Q$ such that $f(b)=y$. Let $b_0 \in P-Q$ be that element. We know that $b_0 \in P-Q$, so $b_0 \in P$ and $b_0 \notin Q$. From that we conclude that $f(b_0) \in f(P)$ and $f(b_0) \notin f(Q)$. Hence $f(b_0) \in f(P)-f(Q)$, so $y \in f(P)-f(Q)$. Therefore $f(P-Q) \subseteq f(P)-f(Q)$. $\square$

I'm not sure about the second part of the proof. My doubts are:

1. I'm not quite sure if we can deduce that $f(b_0) \notin f(Q)$ from $b_0 \notin Q$.
2. The fact that $f$ is bijective allows us to conclude that such $b_0$ is unique, and (for example) it could never be the case of having one element in $P$ and other in $Q$ with the same image (what would implied that such image could be in $f(P-Q)$ but not in $f(P)-f(Q)$), right?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: The argument is correct; your use of bijectivity of $f$ in the second part is fine.

Comment: If by the notation of some set $A$ and some map $f$ the definition is $f(A) = \{y : (\exists x)(x \in A \land (x,y) \in f) \}$, I think what you asked in the first question is correct by definition, beucase $b0 \notin Q$ means $(b0, y) \notin f$ and therefore $f(b0) \notin Q$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott it wouldn't be sufficient to have $f$ injective? Is it necessary to be also surjective?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim that's good point now is more clear thank you

Comment: @Andrew: Injectivity suffices.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim: It is correct, but only because $f$ is injective.

Comment: I wrote some typos in my comment, sorry, but using the same definition the idea is that:
if $f(b0) \in f(Q) \Rightarrow (b0 \in Q \land (b0, f(b0)) \in f)$
thus:
$$b0 \notin Q$$
$$f(b0) \notin f(Q)$$
Feel free to correct me if i interpreted the application of map to a set in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. using the definition of image you have $a \in f(Q)$ if and only if there exist an element $b \in Q$ such  that $f(b) =a$. substituting $a$ with $f(b_0)$ in the definition you get that $f(b_0) \in Q$ then $b_0 \in Q$ taking the contrapositive of this statement you get if $b_0 \notin Q$ then $f(b_0) \notin Q$. ($a \implies  b$ if and only if  $\neg b \implies \neg a$).
2. In general for any function $f:A\to B$ you do not have this property a very trivial example is a function $f:\{0,1\}\to \{0\}$ We have that $f(\{0\})-f(\{1\})=\emptyset$ but $f(\{0\}-\{1\})=f(\{0\})=\{0\}$

Comment: It is indeed the contrapositive, makes more sense now! About the point 2. why $f$ has to be bijective? I thought it was only necessary to have $f$ injective(?)

Comment: @Andrew yes injection is all that is required since you can just consider f as a bijection between A -> f(A) by restricting the codomain to the range. You can do this since f(X) and f(Y) are subsets of f(A) the set f(X)-f(Y) is the same in B and in f(A). Note that for example the complement of a set changes according to the superset in which it takes place